# Correct use of POSIX' pthread_exit and pthread_join

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to get the concepts of returning a value from a pthread, and catching that value, but I cannot understand what is going on, or how to make it work. I have this simple program that creates a single thread, this thread exits with int value 100, and then I try to catch that value with pthread_join:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *doStuff(void *param) {
    int a = 100;
    pthread_exit(a);
}

void main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    int a;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, doStuff, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

It works, but throws off a few warnings:

```
./teste.c: In function ‘doStuff’:
./teste.c:7:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_exit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from ./teste.c:2:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:241:13: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
./teste.c: In function ‘main’:
./teste.c:17:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘pthread_join’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from ./teste.c:2:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:249:12: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
```

I don't understand why I'm getting those warnings, and honestly I don't understand why this is working either, because I thought I had to return a void pointer on pthread_exit.

This is a simple example that I'm trying to get to work so that I'm able to finish another program that I'm trying to create, in which I will have an array of threads, each of them calculating a single float value, and I want to store each of those calculated values into an array of floats using pthread_exit and pthread_join, but I don't really know how to store the values from pthread_join into an array.

Comment: "I don't understand why I'm getting those warnings" - because `int` is not `void *`, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread_exit` takes a `void*`, not an `int`. (Note that calling `pthread_exit(x)` is the same as simply returning `x` from your thread function.)

The simplest fix for your issue is to pass the thread function a pointer to `int` in which to store the produced value:

```
void *doStuff(void *param) {
    int a = 100;
    *(int*)param = a;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    int a;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, doStuff, &a);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

EDIT: If you really need to use the return value of the thread function as to communicate the result, you have a couple of options.

(1) cast the return value in and out of `void*`:

```
void *doStuff(void *param) {
    int a = 100;
    return (void*)a;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, doStuff, NULL);
    void* ptr;
    pthread_join(thread, &ptr);
    int a = (int)ptr;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

This feels a bit hackish, because it is. If you are certain that casting to-and-from `void*` will preserve the value of an `int` on every platform you will ever target, then by all means cast away.

(2) Return a pointer to dynamically allocated storage containing the return value:

```
void *doStuff(void *param) {
    int a = 100;
    int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    assert(ptr); /* I'm lazy, sue me. */
    *ptr = a;
    return ptr;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, doStuff, NULL);
    void* ptr;
    pthread_join(thread, &ptr);
    int a = *(int*)ptr;
    free(ptr);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

(3) Make a structure to encapsulate all the in/out parameters of your thread (Heavyweight, but nicely explicit):

```
struct foo {
  int input1;
  int input2;
  int result;
};

void *doStuff(void *param) {
    foo* f = param;
    f->result = f->input1 + f->input2;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    foo* ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    assert(ptr);
    ptr->input1 = 5;
    ptr->input2 = 3;

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, doStuff, ptr);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    printf("%d\n", ptr->result);
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case this is a valid solution, but for the main program I'm working on, I'm already using pthread_create to pass the threads an array of values to be worked on. Is there any other way for me to catch the values returned by all threads?

Comment: It is not wrong to pass an `int` as the return of a pthread, you just need to make the proper cast. This will not work 100% if `sizeof(void *) < sizeof(int)`, witch I doubt to be true in any platform, don´t know if the standard says something about this.
Pass the address of a local variable is not always possible, and should not be recommended.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel This falls in the area of "things I expect are true of all reasonable implementations but may not be guaranteed by the standard". From N1570: 6.3.2.3/5 and /6 specify int-to-pointer and pointer-to-int conversions (respectively) as being implementation-defined. AFAIK, the only integer types for which the standard *guarantees* that int-to-pointer-to-int produces the same result are `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` (7.20.1.4/1) which are optional. Honestly, I'd file a bug report for any implementation that didn't preserve the value in int-to-pointer-to-int conversions.

Comment: Footnote 67 says "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment." Footnotes are non-normative, but this does indicate that implementations are strongly encouraged to support int-to-void*-to-int conversions.

Comment: I have posted a new answer. Pls comment if it is wrong. I will correct it then.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one more way to avoid all warnings. I have actually got this solution by reading multiple SO answers.

```
void *thread_fn(void *arg) {
    int a = 100;
    return (void*)(intptr_t)a;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    void* ptr;
    int a;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_fn, &a);
    pthread_join(thread, &ptr);
    a = (intptr_t)ptr;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

In the above code snippet, `return (void*)(intptr_t)a;` here we are first type casting integer to get an integer type that's the same size as a pointer(intptr_t). And then we can now typecast it to void pointer. Same is the case with `a = (intptr_t)ptr;`

Comment: This is equivalent to the variant in my answer "cast the return value in and out of `void*`", and it has the same problem: there's no guarantee that all possible values of `int` are representable in a `void*` or `intptr_t`. I know of no such implementation - it would be fairly perverse - but the standard allows for e.g. `int` to be 64 bits with 32 bit pointers.